# How do you use SparseArrays.sparse?

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68423583/how-to-efficiently-construct-a-large-sparsearray-packages-for-this) and I have a similar problem. I want to *in-place* update sparse matrices multiple times, and it seems to me that `SparseArrays.sparse!` is my best bet. However, I don't quite understand the documentation, which says I may call

```
sparse!(I, J, V, csrrowptr, csrcolval, csrnzval, I, J, V)
```

My questions are:

1. What is the first set of `I, J, V`?
2. What is the second set of `I, J, V`?
3. Suppose I have created a matrix `A = sparse(I,J,V)` and I want to in-place update `A`. How can I get `csrrowptr, csrcolval, csrnzval`? `A` by default has a CSC format, not CSR.
4. Can I get a working example of `sparse!`?

Thank you.

Comment: The docstring, together with the one from `sparse`, is quite exhaustive. What are information is missing exactly from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the documentation, it definitely feels (and is) a package internal function of SparseArrays. In any case, per your questions (not in order):

Q4 (the easiest) do `@edit sparse([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[5,6,7])` at the REPL, and search for `sparse!` in the edited file, this will show how `sparse` uses `sparse!` internally.

Q1 The first `I, J, V` are the inputs, giving the usual columns indices, row indices, values. Note, these are not the internal CSC storage vectors of the resulting matrix.

Q2 The second `I, J, V` are the arrays used in the resulting sparse matrix as the internal CSC storage vectors. Since the input is not necessary after `sparse!` call, instead of deallocating input and allocating internal CSC vectors, the input memory vectors can be reused (other vectors than `I, J, K` can be passed as output, especially if the input vectors have too little memory to hold CSC representation).

Q3 Getting the CSR-ish representation created inside `sparse!` is easy - they are in the vectors you pass as `csrrowptr, csrcolval, csrnzval`. The vectors need to have enough memory, and are populated by `sparse!`.

The whole point of `sparse!` is to make no allocations/deallocations. The memory management is done by a 'parent' interface (`sparse` in this case). This allows direct non-allocating processing when the memory is already allocated or recycled from another variable.

It took a bit of fiddling, but here is a demo of `sparse!` usage:

```
julia> I = sizehint!([1,2,3,1], 5)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 1

julia> J = sizehint!([3, 2, 1, 2], 5)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 2
 1
 2

julia> V = sizehint!([6,7,8,9],5)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 6
 7
 8
 9
```

Now setting up working memory for `sparse!`:

```
julia> my_klasttouch = Vector{Int}(undef, 10);

julia> my_csrrowptr = Vector{Int}(undef, 10);

julia> my_csrcolval = Vector{Int}(undef, 10);

julia> my_csrnzval = Vector{Int}(undef, 10);
```

Finally:

```
julia> M = SparseArrays.sparse!(
  I, J, V, 3, 3, +, 
  my_klasttouch, my_csrrowptr, my_csrcolval, my_csrnzval, 
  I, J, V
)
3×3 SparseMatrixCSC{Int64, Int64} with 4 stored entries:
 ⋅  9  6
 ⋅  7  ⋅
 8  ⋅  ⋅
```

To see how the input memory becomes part of the returned object:

```
julia> M.colptr   # this is from returned object
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 4
 5

julia> I
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 4
 5
```

Note that `I` and `M.colpotr` use the same memory.

Given the above, I would suggest, before using this function, to go over the implementation code and understand the algorithm carefully.